# tempered distribution

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

The space $S$ is the space of all smooth functions $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ such that for every (integer) $N$, 
$|\phi(x)|\cdot|x|^N\to 0$ as $|x|\to \infty$ (rapidly decreasing functions).

Given locally integrable function $f$ such that for all $A>0$

$\int_{|x|\leq A}|f|\leq A^M$

(for some fixed integer $M>0$)

How can I show that 
the integral

$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f\cdot \phi $

is well defined for every $\phi\in S$?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $m_0>0$ such as $|\phi(x)|\leq\dfrac 1{\vert x\vert^{M+2}}$ for all $x$ such as $\vert x\vert>m_0$.

For any $m\geq m_0$, we have that $$\int_{m<\vert x\vert\leq m+1} |f(x)| |\phi(x)| dx \leq \frac{(m+1)^M}{m^{M+2}}$$
hence the convergence of
$$\int_{m_0<\vert x\vert\leq m_0+n} |f(x)| |\phi(x)| dx\leq\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(m_0+k+1)^M}{(m_0+k)^{M+2}}$$ as $n$ goes to infinity, and the result.